# Access a methods variable

Tags: python, django

I want to access the `gallery_path` variable from my `create_directory` method as a parameter in my `gallery` model field. Is this possible?

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="category")
    category_description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, default=1)
    gallery = models.ImageField(upload_to=gallery_path)

    def create_directory(self):
        global gallery_path
        gallery_path = os.path.abspath(
            os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.slug))
        if not os.path.isdir(gallery_path):
            os.mkdir(gallery_path)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.create_directory()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.slug))
        # os.rmdir(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.slug))
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_title
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: so what's the problem with your current code?
Ah, I got you. You can't affect image upload path after model loading this way. Models is loaded on application startup, and you're trying to change it after loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't affect image upload path after model loading this way. 
Models is loaded on application startup, and you're trying to change it after loading.

But you can pass callable to parameter "upload_to" and it will be called every time when new file is being uploaded:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    # Need to be defined before the field    
    def get_image_path(self, filename): 
        gallery_path = os.path.abspath(
        os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.slug))
        if not os.path.isdir(gallery_path):
            os.mkdir(gallery_path)
        return os.path.join(gallery_path, filename)

    gallery = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)
```

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to